# How do I efficiently locate a merge module for this MS patch

Tags: installation, patch

Microsoft have published this patch:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2051a0c1-c9b5-4b0a-a8f5-770a549fd78c

Where can I find the merge module for this (if any). Is there a standard location I should look in to find these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has released very, very few merge modules... and none that work like a Windows Update patch, because their patches generally use different guts than Windows Installer. So, unfortunately, I highly doubt you'll find one.

And I wouldn't recommend trying to make this patch into a merge module. Instead, you could create your own simple scripted install for both the redistributable and then the patch with a command-line like `patch.exe /quiet /passive /norestart /o /n /f > patch.log` -- see [KB article #262841](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;262841) for more details.

Comment: Indeed. I used a program that diffed the filesystem and registry before and after the patch installation and it found >110 file changes and >35000 reg changes!

Comment: Yup... and you can bet a good portion of those changes are editing a file or entry in-place, not overwriting it with a new file or value--which is what the MSM would typically do.

Comment: Visual C++ runtime libraries have to be installed into Global Assembly Cache; you have to use Windows Installer to do it. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196944/how-do-i-efficiently-locate-a-merge-module-for-this-ms-patch/7208404#7208404) on how to get the updated merge modules.

Answer (score 1):

Install [this update to your Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11895), it will update the corresponding merge modules to the versions of the runtime delivered in the update you link to. The merge modules are in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules`.

*The updates you link to are intended for the end-users, not developers, hence they don't contain the merge modules. The updates to the Visual Studio, on the other side, do contain the updated merge modules because they target developers.*